# Add numpy array to list python

Tags: python, list, numpy

Let's say I have two arrays

```
arr1 = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
arr2 = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6]])
```

I want to create a list which contains each sequence of arr1 and arr2. I do that with

```
l = [arr1, arr2[0], arr2[1]]
```

But the length of arr2 can change, how can I create a list with loop for ? Or another way ?

Comment: This smells like an [XY-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You should ask what you REALLY want.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `*` unpacking:

```py
l = [arr1, *arr2]
```